# T-SQL - Joining multiple tables results in duplicate rows

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I am struggeling to get the following result from below sample [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cb88e/1).

Result:

[image]

Source tables:

[image]

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cb88e/1)

The idea is to create a single row for each `RecordID` by finding the *max count* of Budget and Forecast IDs to create the other columns (leaving columns cells empty if no value for that Budget or Forecast ID exists).

I tried with `PIVOT` function but couldn't get even near a decent result.

**UPDATE**:
Please see below image where I tried to explain the expected **output**:

**In words**: ***for each*** BudgetID that belongs to a RecordID create **separate** columns for **BDate**, **Result** (Percentage * BAmount of Records table) and **Status**.

In my example RecordID **55** has **two** entries in the Budget table - therefore **2x3** columns are needed to show each *date*, *result* and *status* in its own column in a **single row** for this RecordID.

Since RecordID **77** has the **most** (three) entries in the Budget table it is used to create 3x3 columns over all rows.

The same goes for Forecast.

[image: output]

I hope you can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: can you please add expected output for this

Comment: Not clear to me

Comment: please see update for detailed explanation.

Comment: You must alter my answer as add `column names`. What columns are you needed. Let me know what you got...!

Comment: SQL doesn't have the syntax to add new columns based on new data.  Do you know that there will always be a maximum of 3 Budget IDs for each RecordID?  If so, you can write a pivot style query to add Result1, Result2 and Result3 columns.  If not, and you don't know how many Result columns you need until you run your query, then you must write Dynamic SQL.  That is, code that reads your data, then writes a new query based on the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good day,

> **Note!** My goal is to help the reader to learn and not to provide final query as a solution for his homework. Therefore I will present the solution in two steps, and I will add several "PRINT" command in the dynamic solution, so the reader will have option to check the intermediate step in the work.

### The DDL+DML provided by the OP:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Budget;
CREATE TABLE Budget
    (BudgetID int, RecordID int, BDate date,Percentage int, [Status] varchar(50));
INSERT INTO Budget
    (BudgetID, RecordID, BDate,Percentage,Status)
VALUES
    (1, 55, '2017-01-01', 60, 'ordered'),
    (2, 55, '2017-03-24', 40, 'ordered'),
    (3, 66, '2018-08-15', 100, 'invoiced'),
    (4, 77, '2018-12-02', 25, 'paid'),
    (5, 77, '2018-09-10', 35, 'ordered'),
    (6, 77, '2019-07-13', 40, 'ordered')
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Forecast;
CREATE TABLE Forecast
    (ForecastID int, RecordID int, FDate date, Percentage int);
INSERT INTO Forecast
    (ForecastID, RecordID, FDate,Percentage)
VALUES
    (1, 55, '2020-12-01', 100),
    (2, 77, '2023-05-17', 25),
    (3, 77, '2024-11-28', 75)
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Records;
CREATE TABLE Records
    (RecordID int, BAmount int, FAmount int, Name varchar(40), Description varchar(40) )
;
INSERT INTO Records
   (RecordID, BAmount,FAmount,Name, Description)
VALUES
    (55, 15000, 33000, 'Prod1', 'Desc1' ),
     (66, 22000, 17500, 'Prod2', 'Desc2' ),
    (77, 40000, 44000, 'Prod3', 'Desc3' )
GO

select * from Budget
select * from Forecast
select * from Records
```

### Let's first show a simple static solution

This base on the knowledge that we have maximum of three rows for each RecordID in the Budget table and maximum of two rows for each RecordID in the Forecast table. This will help to understand the dynamic solution I will show next

```
;With CteBudget as (
    select 
        b.BDate, b.BudgetID, b.Percentage, b.RecordID, b.Status
        ,RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by b.RecordID order by b.BudgetID)
    from Budget b
),
CteForecast as (
    select 
        f.FDate, f.ForecastID, f.Percentage, f.RecordID
        ,RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by f.RecordID order by f.ForecastID)
    from Forecast f
)
select 
    r.RecordID, r.Name, r.Description, 

    b1.BDate BDate1, (b1.Percentage * r.BAmount)/100 BResult1, b1.Status BStatus1, 
    b2.BDate BDate2, (b2.Percentage * r.BAmount)/100 BResult2, b2.Status BStatus2,
    b3.BDate BDate3, (b3.Percentage * r.BAmount)/100 BResult3, b3.Status BStatus3, 

    f1.FDate FDate1, (f1.Percentage * r.BAmount)/100 FResult1,
    f2.FDate FDate2, (f2.Percentage * r.BAmount)/100 FResult2

from Records r
left join CteBudget b1 on r.RecordID = b1.RecordID and b1.RN = 1
left join CteBudget b2 on r.RecordID = b2.RecordID and b2.RN = 2
left join CteBudget b3 on r.RecordID = b3.RecordID and b3.RN = 3
left join CteForecast f1 on r.RecordID = f1.RecordID and f1.RN = 1
left join CteForecast f2 on r.RecordID = f2.RecordID and f2.RN = 2
--where r.RecordID = 77
GO
```

> **Note!** For static solution and without indexes (as I will add in the end), the above solution is VERY bad regarding performance, but once we add the right index and as a base for a dynamic solution this option should fit well.

### Now we can present the dynamic solution.

```
-- Get number of columns
Declare @NumBudget tinyint
Declare @NumForecast tinyint
SELECT @NumBudget = MAX(C) FROM (
    select COUNT(RecordID) C
    from Budget
    GROUP BY RecordID
) t
SELECT @NumForecast = MAX(C) FROM (
    select COUNT(RecordID) C
    from Forecast
    GROUP BY RecordID
) t
---------------------------------------------
DECLARE @SQLString1 nvarchar(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @SQLString2 nvarchar(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @loop int = 1;
WHILE @loop <= @NumBudget BEGIN 
    SET @SQLString1 = @SQLString1 + N'
    b' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@loop) + '.BDate BDate' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@loop) + ', (b' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@loop) + '.Percentage * r.BAmount)/100 BResult' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@loop) + ', b' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@loop) + '.Status BStatus' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@loop) + ', '

    SET @SQLString2 = @SQLString2 + N'
    left join CteBudget b' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@loop) + ' on r.RecordID = b' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@loop) + '.RecordID and b' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@loop) + '.RN = 1'

    SET @loop = @loop + 1
END
SET @loop = 1

WHILE @loop <= @NumForecast BEGIN  
    SET @SQLString1 = @SQLString1 + N'
    f' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@loop) + '.FDate FDate' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@loop) + ', (f' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@loop) + '.Percentage * r.BAmount)/100 FResult' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@loop) + ','

    SET @SQLString2 = @SQLString2 + N'
    left join CteForecast f' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@loop) + ' on r.RecordID = f' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@loop) + '.RecordID and f' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@loop) + '.RN = 1'

    SET @loop = @loop + 1
END
SET @SQLString1 = STUFF (@SQLString1, LEN(@SQLString1) , 1 , '')  
PRINT '/************************************************/'
PRINT @SQLString1
PRINT @SQLString2
PRINT '/************************************************/'

DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQLString = N'
;With CteBudget as (
    select 
        b.BDate, b.BudgetID, b.Percentage, b.RecordID, b.Status
        ,RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by b.RecordID order by b.BudgetID)
    from Budget b
),
CteForecast as (
    select 
        f.FDate, f.ForecastID, f.Percentage, f.RecordID
        ,RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by f.RecordID order by f.ForecastID)
    from Forecast f
)
select 
    r.RecordID, r.Name, r.Description, 
'
+ @SQLString1
+ N'
from Records r'
+ @SQLString2

print @SQLString

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
GO
```

> **IMPORTANT!** This solution is not necessarily the one that gives the best performance, but the one that is probably the simplest to follow and understand. On production once we will have the real DDL+DML and the server will have the statistics, then we will be able to improve the performance and chose best solution for our specific case.

### Indexes

> **Note!** The above solution might lead to a lot of sorting of the data, and having the right indexes is HIGHLY important here! It is important to test several different options and select the best.

For the sake of the forum (or whatever you call stackoverflow which in my opinion is not a discussion forum interface but Q&A interface), I add queries to create the CLUSTERED INDEX which I assume you have in the production, and an optional NONCLUSTERED INDEX which you should test (I did not tested other options and this is imply the first that came to my mind, so it is recommended to keep check for the right index with the real DDL+DML).

```
-- CLUSTERED INDEX
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Budget_BudgetID
    ON dbo.Budget (BudgetID);   
GO 
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Forecast_ForecastID
    ON dbo.Forecast (ForecastID);   
GO 
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Records_RecordID  
    ON dbo.Records (RecordID);   
GO 

-- NONCLUSTERED INDEX
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NX_Budget_RecordID_BudgetID
    ON dbo.Budget (RecordID,BudgetID);   
GO 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NX_Forecast_RecordID_ForecastID
    ON dbo.Forecast (RecordID,ForecastID);   
GO 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NX_Records_RecordID_RecordID  
    ON dbo.Records (RecordID);   
GO
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I was able to adjust the sample to the productive data.

Comment: You are welcome @ratanmalko . I am glad to hear that I could help :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think i would do:

```
select Max(BudgetId) as BudgetID, RecordID
into #MBudget
from Budget
group by RecordID

select B.* 
into #MaxB
from #MBudget M
inner join Budget B
on M.BudgetID = B.BudgetID
and M.RecordID = B.RecordID

--The above will then only have the "maximum" BudgetID data from the table.

-- You need to then do the same with the Forecast table

select Max(ForecastId) as ForecastID, RecordID
into #MForecast
from Forecast
group by RecordID

select F.* 
into #MaxF
from #MForecast M
inner join Forecast F
on M.ForecastID = F.ForecastID
and M.RecordID = F.RecordID

-- Join them together on the RecordID

select *  -- you will need to pick the required fields
from #MaxF F
inner join #MaxB B 
on F.RecordID = B.RecordID
inner join Record R
on F.RecordID = R.RecordID
```

I think this will get you there, i'm not a big fan of fiddle and so did it in my head.

I do agree a little with the guys, you could have been clearer but hope this gets you where you need to be.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, we create Dynamic query as multiple join.

**Input Tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE #Budget (BudgetID int, RecordID int, BDate date,Percentage int, [Status] varchar(50));
INSERT INTO #Budget(BudgetID, RecordID, BDate,Percentage,Status)
VALUES(1, 55, '2017-01-01', 60, 'ordered'),(2, 55, '2017-03-24', 40, 'ordered'),(3, 66, '2018-08-15', 100, 'invoiced'),(4, 77, '2018-12-02', 25, 'paid'),(5, 77, '2018-09-10', 35, 'ordered'),(6, 77, '2019-07-13', 40, 'ordered')

CREATE TABLE #Forecast(ForecastID int, RecordID int, FDate date, Percentage int)
INSERT INTO #Forecast(ForecastID, RecordID, FDate,Percentage)
VALUES(4, 77, '2018-07-18', 24),(1, 55, '2020-12-01', 100),(2, 77, '2023-05-17', 25),(3, 77, '2024-11-28', 75)

CREATE TABLE #Records(RecordID int, BAmount int, FAmount int, Name varchar(40), Description varchar(40) )
INSERT INTO #Records(RecordID, BAmount,FAmount,Name, Description)
VALUES(55, 15000, 33000, 'Prod1', 'Desc1' ),(66, 22000, 17500, 'Prod2', 'Desc2' ),(77, 40000, 44000, 'Prod3', 'Desc3' )
```

**Final Join Query**

```
 select * from (select r1.RecordID, f1.FDate fdate1, b1.BDate bdate1
 , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by r1.recordid order by (select NULL)) rn from #Records r1
 join #Forecast f1
 on r1.RecordID = f1.RecordID
 and r1.RecordID = 77
 join #Budget b1
 on r1.RecordID = b1.RecordID
)t1 join (select r2.RecordID, f2.FDate fdate2, b2.BDate bdate2
 , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by r2.recordid order by (select NULL)) rn from #Records r2
 join #Forecast f2
 on r2.RecordID = f2.RecordID
 and r2.RecordID = 77
 join #Budget b2
 on r2.RecordID = b2.RecordID
)t2 on t1.RecordID = t2.RecordID and t1.rn < t2.rn join (select r3.RecordID, f3.FDate fdate3, b3.BDate bdate3
 , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by r3.recordid order by (select NULL)) rn from #Records r3
 join #Forecast f3
 on r3.RecordID = f3.RecordID
 and r3.RecordID = 77
 join #Budget b3
 on r3.RecordID = b3.RecordID
)t3 on t2.RecordID = t3.RecordID and t2.rn < t3.rn join (select r4.RecordID, f4.FDate fdate4, b4.BDate bdate4
 , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by r4.recordid order by (select NULL)) rn from #Records r4
 join #Forecast f4
 on r4.RecordID = f4.RecordID
 and r4.RecordID = 77
 join #Budget b4
 on r4.RecordID = b4.RecordID
)t4 on t3.RecordID = t4.RecordID and t3.rn < t4.rn join (select r5.RecordID, f5.FDate fdate5, b5.BDate bdate5
 , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by r5.recordid order by (select NULL)) rn from #Records r5
 join #Forecast f5
 on r5.RecordID = f5.RecordID
 and r5.RecordID = 77
 join #Budget b5
 on r5.RecordID = b5.RecordID
)t5 on t4.RecordID = t5.RecordID and t4.rn < t5.rn join (select r6.RecordID, f6.FDate fdate6, b6.BDate bdate6
 , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by r6.recordid order by (select NULL)) rn from #Records r6
 join #Forecast f6
 on r6.RecordID = f6.RecordID
 and r6.RecordID = 77
 join #Budget b6
 on r6.RecordID = b6.RecordID
)t6 on t5.RecordID = t6.RecordID and t5.rn < t6.rn join (select r7.RecordID, f7.FDate fdate7, b7.BDate bdate7
 , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by r7.recordid order by (select NULL)) rn from #Records r7
 join #Forecast f7
 on r7.RecordID = f7.RecordID
 and r7.RecordID = 77
 join #Budget b7
 on r7.RecordID = b7.RecordID
)t7 on t6.RecordID = t7.RecordID and t6.rn < t7.rn join (select r8.RecordID, f8.FDate fdate8, b8.BDate bdate8
 , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by r8.recordid order by (select NULL)) rn from #Records r8
 join #Forecast f8
 on r8.RecordID = f8.RecordID
 and r8.RecordID = 77
 join #Budget b8
 on r8.RecordID = b8.RecordID
)t8 on t7.RecordID = t8.RecordID and t7.rn < t8.rn join (select r9.RecordID, f9.FDate fdate9, b9.BDate bdate9
 , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by r9.recordid order by (select NULL)) rn from #Records r9
 join #Forecast f9
 on r9.RecordID = f9.RecordID
 and r9.RecordID = 77
 join #Budget b9
 on r9.RecordID = b9.RecordID
)t9 on t8.RecordID = t9.RecordID and t8.rn < t9.rn
```

First verify the OP from the IP table and above query. If answer is accepted, you will use the following SP.

**SP 1**

```
exec rownumber

create procedure rownumber as                                           --1st sp.
declare @r int = 1, @select nvarchar(100) = 'select * from ', @count int, @finalquery nvarchar(max) = N'', @out nvarchar(max)
begin
 set @count = (select Count(*) from (select r.RecordID, f1.FDate fdate1, b1.BDate bdate1
  , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by r.recordid order by (select NULL)) rn from #Records r
  join #Forecast f1
  on r.RecordID = f1.RecordID
  and r.RecordID = 77
  join #Budget b1
  on r.RecordID = b1.RecordID
  )t
 )
 if @count > 2
 begin
  while @count >= @r
  begin
   exec multyJoin @r, @out output
   set @finalquery += @out
   set @r = @r + 1
  end
 end
 else begin
  select * from (
   select r.RecordID, f1.FDate fdate1, b1.BDate bdate1
   , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by r.recordid order by (select NULL)) rn from #Records r
   join #Forecast f1
   on r.RecordID = f1.RecordID
   and r.RecordID = 77
   join #Budget b1
   on r.RecordID = b1.RecordID
  )t
 end
 set @finalquery = stuff(@finalquery,1, 6,@select)
 set @finalquery = REPLACE(@finalquery, 'on t0.RecordID = t1.RecordID and t0.rn < t1.rn ','')
 print @finalquery
 exec sp_executesql @finalquery
end
```

**SP 2**

```
create procedure multyJoin (@r int, @join varchar(max) output) as       --2nd sp. which is called form below sp
declare @cond nvarchar(100), @rvc varchar(3) = convert(int, @r)     ----row number of current in varchar
, @rvp varchar(3) = convert(int, @r-1)      ----row number of previous in varchar
begin

 set @join = ' join (select r'+@rvc+'.RecordID, f'+@rvc+'.FDate fdate'+@rvc+', b'+@rvc+'.BDate bdate'+@rvc+  ---Here add your columns as like as 'Percentage'+@rvc+' * '+@rvc+'BAmount'
  ', ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by r'+@rvc+'.recordid order by (select NULL)) rn from #Records r'+@rvc+'
  join #Forecast f'+@rvc+'
  on r'+@rvc+'.RecordID = f'+@rvc+'.RecordID
  and r'+@rvc+'.RecordID = 77
  join #Budget b'+@rvc+'
  on r'+@rvc+'.RecordID = b'+@rvc+'.RecordID
 )t'+@rvc+
 ' on t'+@rvp+'.RecordID = t'+@rvc+'.RecordID and t'+@rvp+'.rn < t'+@rvc+'.rn'  --Here multiple join has been created. Each table contains one row
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the script. A dynamic query using pivot function would be really great.

Comment: are you reach solution..?

Comment: no solution yet. I was hoping for an example of a dynamic query as stated in your answer.